# Stacked bar chart with chartjs with included values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chart.js

I am trying to create a visitors bar chart with included values, for example:

I want to show a bar chart of **total daily visitors**, and that bar should contain info of **total visitors** and **first time visitors**.

so data for a bar should look like:

```
data: {
    labels: getDataAttributes(data, 'data-date'),
    // an array holding the date of each bar (custom function)
    // for example purposes lets say its just 3 bars
    
    datasets: [{
        label: ['Number of visitors', 'Number of new visitors'],
        data: [[20,15], [25,10], [30, 15]],
        // Here if we would use a simple stacked bar chart the height would be the sum of 2 values
        // e.g.(20+15=35), but I wish that the bar height would be the number of total visitors 20
        // the tooltip should contain values of total visitors and new visitors respectively 20 and 15
    }]
}
```

I looked in the [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) documentation, but found only examples with stacked values and that solution is not applied in my desired design, can someone please reference documentation/articles/tutorials or personal experience or perhaps I should switch to d3js? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define two datasets, the first one would contain the values of new visitors, the second one the values of all visitors.

Then you would define the x-axis as being stacked:

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true
    }],
```

Please take a look at below runnable code snippet to see how it works:

```js
const baseData = [[20,15], [25,10], [30, 15]];

new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['25.10.2020', '26.10.2020', '27.10.2020'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Number of new visitors',
      data: baseData.map(v => v[1]),
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    {
      label: 'Number of visitors',
      data: baseData.map(v => v[0]), 
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="100"></canvas>
```